# In what field is the particle $L=\frac{m}{2}\eta_{\mu\nu}u^{\nu}u^{\mu}+\frac{k\,x^3\,u^0}{((x^1)^2+(x^2)^2+(x^3)^2)^2}$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, energy, lagrangian-formalism, potential

The following Lagrangian  describes the behavior of a charged particle placed in a field.
$$L=\frac{m}{2}\eta_{\mu\nu}u^{\nu}u^{\mu}+\frac{k\,x^3\,u^0}{((x^1)^2+(x^2)^2+(x^3)^2)^2}$$
It is a particular example of the general: 
$$L=\frac{m}{2}\eta_{\mu\nu}u^{\nu}u^{\mu}+kA_{\mu}(x^{\lambda})u^{\mu}$$
I need to understand the field in which the particle is.
I do not know how to determine in which field the particle is, since the generalized potential and not a normal potential appear in the expression.
Thanks for your help

Comment: What are you asking exactly? What do you mean by "which field the particle is"? Do you want the electromagnetic fields corresponding to that potential?

Comment: Yes I want to know the source of the electric field so I have to know the  electromagnetic fields corresponding to that potential, sorry for the inaccuracy

Answer (score 0):

It is quite obvious that

$$A_0 = \dfrac{x^3}{((x^1)^2+(x^2)^2+(x^3)^2)^2},\quad A_i=0.$$

Now the four-potential is $A^\mu = (\Phi,\mathbf{A})$. This together with

$$\mathbf{E}=-\nabla\Phi-\partial_t \mathbf{A},\quad \mathbf{B}=\nabla\times \mathbf{A}$$

should be enough to find the field.

Comment: Sorry if I'm not very autonomous but in addition to doing the $\nabla \times A $ I do not know how to get the field. Would you do me the great favour to do some steps?

Comment: From the above you have that $\mathbf{A} =0$. This already means that $\mathbf{B} = 0$. To get $\mathbf{E}$ you need just the gradient of $\Phi$.